How to allow telegram bot to send messages in group?
I intend to implement a telegram bot integration for my service. I have experience developing discord bots and I find telegram permission system pretty simplified. I have invited a bot to my group. It seems that if I remove the permission to send messages from all members my bot won't be able to send messages.
I've seen a post that says, that in order to be able to send messages I need to make my bot admin. I'd rather prefer to add a write permission to my bot than make it an admin.
Is it really necessary to make the bot an admin?
Thanks.


Is it really necessary to make the bot an admin?

If you choose not to allow members to send messages, then yes, you have to set your bot as admin.
I don't see any problem with this as long as you have full control of the bot you add. You can also further restrict admin's actions.


Thanky you! didn't know admins have their own permissions!
